# Keep specific HTML tags after string is passed into .text() function

Tags: javascript, html, regex

If I have the following string:

```
hello



goodbye
```

Can I set that string as the content of a div but keep the carriage returns?

```
jQuery('<div class="myTooltip">').text(theString);
```

Atm, .text() returns this:

```
hello<br> <br> <br> <br> goodbye
```

I am unable to use .html() because of cross side scripting concerns.

Could I perhaps use some regex on my string to keep the carraige returns from being converted to text?

If not regex, is there another option?

Comment: A carriage return is an `\n` in js, you can convert the <br> to this ?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use replace to convert`'\n'` or `'\n\r'` characters with `'<br />'`

Here an example:

```
var myString = 'some text \n';
var parsed= myString.replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />');
console.log(parsed);
```

Fully working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/r6xrf5wh/1/

Just inspect the "the red box" to see the 
 automatically inserted when using line break in the input field.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#result {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
<script>
window.parse = function() {
    var elm = document.getElementById('test');
    var elmText = elm.value;
    var parsed= elmText.replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />');
    var elmResult = document.getElementById('result');
    elmResult.innerHTML = parsed;
};

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="test" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    <button type="button" onclick="parse()">Click Me!</button>
    <div id="result">x</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Script that will work in most of cases. It was written by me some time ago as the regex replace(/\n\r?/g, '') was not always working and i also needed to get rid of carrige returns :)

```
function (str) {
    var cleanStr = "";
    if(str!=null && str!=""){
        for(var i=0; i< str.length; i++){
            if(!str[i].charCodeAt(0) == 10 && !str[i].charCodeAt(0) == 13){
                cleanStr+=str[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return cleanStr;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS:

```
$('<div class="myTooltip" style="white-space: pre-line;"></div>').text(theString);
```